# regex to get the last item after space

Tags: regex, go

How to get the last item by regex?

```
"Read the information failed.
111 a bcd

SAM Error Log not up supported"
```

I did this

```
111\s(.*)$
```

but it gives me

```
output = "a bcd sam"
```

But, I want output of regex which starts with 111 as

```
output = "sam" // for the line starts with 111
```

Also, how can i make change if there is any space before 111?

you can test this at https://regex-golang.appspot.com/assets/html/index.html

Comment: You want to obtain the last chunk of non-whitespace characters if the string starts with `111`?

Comment: yes true. in this case i wanted "sam". i.e. last element after white space

Comment: If `111` should not be checked, then `\S+$` should suffice.

Comment: but the string starting with 111

Comment: Isn't a non-regex way easier? `func Index(s, sep string) int` + `func Split(s, sep string) []string` can yield the expected result.

Comment: But I want to use the regex. I already used that but I am not getting the last element. Please see how I did in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `111\s(.*)$` matches `111` anywhere inside the string (the first occurrence) and then captures into Submatch 1 **any** 0+ characters up to the end of the string.

If there is a space before the last `sam`, you may use

```
^111.*\s(\S+)$
```

[image]

**Pattern explanation**:

- `^` - start of string
- `111` - a literal substring `111`
- `.*` - any characters, 0 or more, as many as possible up to the *last*...
- `\s` - whitespace
- `(\S+)` - Submatch 1 capturing one or more non-whitespace characters
- `$` - end of string.

If you want to get the ***line*** that starts with `111` (and any leading whitespace is allowed) and has some whitespace after which your submatch is located, you may consider either

```
(?m)^\s*111[^\r\n]*\s(\S+)$
```

(a `.` is replaced with `[^\r\n]` because in Go regex, a dot `.` matches any character *incl.* a newline), or - to make sure you only match *horizontal* whitespace:

```
(?m)^[^\S\r\n]*111[^\r\n]*[^\S\r\n](\S+)$
```

or even

```
(?m)^[^\S\r\n]*111[^\r\n]*[^\S\r\n](\S+)$
```

**Explanation**:

- `(?m)^` - start of the line (due to the `(?m)` MULTILINE modifier, the `^` now matches a *line* start and `$` will match the *line* end)
- `[^\S\r\n]*` - zero or more whitespaces except LF and CR (=*horizontal whitespace*)
- `111` - a literal `111`
- `[^\r\n]*` - any 0+ characters other than CR and LF as many as possible up to the last....
- `[^\S\r\n]` - horizontal space
- `(\S+)`  - Submatch 1 capturing 1+ non-whitespace chars
- `$` - end of line (prepend with `[^\S\r\n]*` or `[^\S\n]*` to allow trailing horizontal whitespace)

Here is a [Go demo](https://play.golang.org/p/u4dLggL4RT):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    s := `Read SMART Log Directory failed.
    111 a bcd sam
       111 sam
     SMART Error Log not supported`
    rex := regexp.MustCompile(`(?m)^[^\S\r\n]*111[^\r\n]*[^\S\r\n](\S+)$`)
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", rex.FindAllStringSubmatch(s,-1))
}
```

Output: `[][]string{[]string{"    111 a bcd sam", "sam"}, []string{"       111 sam", "sam"}}`

Comment: yes but it should work for the line starts with 111.

Comment: No problem, it is the same, just add it to the pattern. The point is the `\s`. It is what makes this pattern work.

Comment: thanks very much. I have updated the string little. can you explain me hw it will work for that string?

Comment: Your string is multiline. Either you split the string into an array of *trimmed* lines and use the regex above, or use `(?m)^\s*111.*\s(\S+)$`

Comment: I think `(?m)^[^\S\r\n]*111[^\r\n]*[^\S\r\n](\S+)$` is safer to use with a multiline string.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
\s(\w+)$ // The output will be `sam`
```

This means capture the last string (`$`) after a whitespace.

Comment: it must start with 111

Comment: can you show a concrete example with the desired result you want to obtain?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
^\s*1{3}.*\s(\S+)$
```

`^` start of line

`\s*` 0 or more occurrences of space in the beginning

`1{3}` followed by three ones (i.e. 111)

`.*` followed by anything

`\s` followed by space

`(\S+)$` ending with non-space characters. First capture group.