# Golang - extract links using regex

Tags: regex, go

## Golang - extract links using regex

I need to get all links from text which are in specific domain `example.de` using Regex in Go

Below are all possible links that should be extracted:

```sh
https://example.de 
https://example.de/
https://example.de/home
https://example.de/home/
https://example.de/home some text that should not be extracted
https://abc.example.de
https://abc.example.de/
https://abc.example.de/home
https://abc.example.de/home
https://abc.example.de/home some text that should not be extracted
```

### What I already tried

I used this website to check if my regex are correct: https://regex101.com/r/ohxUcG/2
and here are combinations that failed:

- `https?://*.+example.de*.+` failed on expression `https://abc.example.de/a1b2c3    dsadsa` getting whole text to the `\n` instead of `https://abc.example.de/a1b2c3` without `dsadsa`
- `https?://*.+example.de*.+\s(\w+)$` this gets links that are terminated only with space but sometimes links can be terminated with `\n` or `\t` etc.

### Resources which may be useful

- [golang regexp.MatchString handle url match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67159622/golang-regexp-matchstring-handle-url-match)
- [regex to get the last item after space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38451002/regex-to-get-the-last-item-after-space)
- [Is there a way to match everything except a constant string using Go.Regexp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42515407/is-there-a-way-to-match-everything-except-a-constant-string-using-go-regexp)
- [Golang regexp to match string until a given sequence of characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54114352/golang-regexp-to-match-string-until-a-given-sequence-of-characters)

Comment: Do you mean these strings are part of a longer text? Try `(?:https?://)?(?:[^/.]+\.)*\bexample\.de(?:/[^/\s]+)*/?`. See https://regex101.com/r/ohxUcG/6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```golang
(?:https?://)?(?:[^/.]+\.)*\bexample\.de\b(?:/[^/\s]+)*/?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ohxUcG/7). *Details*:

- `(?:https?://)?` - an optional `http://` or `https://` string
- `(?:[^/.]+\.)*`  - zero or more sequences of one or more chars other than a `/` and `.` chars and then a `.` char
- `\bexample\.de\b` - a whole word `example.de`
- `(?:/[^/\s]+)*` - zero or more repetitions of `/` and then one or more chars other than whitespace and `/`
- `/?` - an optional `/` char.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have one last question how this regex will look like if there would be more domains like example.nl or example.fr not only example.de, thanks in advance!

Comment: @mikolajsemeniuk Replace `\bexample\.de\b` with `\bexample\.(?:de|fr|nl|co\.uk|etc.)\b`